# Java: Why can't represents +128?

Tags: java, bitset

This portion of code should returns the representation in LittleEndian of 10000000, then 128, but it returns -128. I know that 128 is the same as -128 in binary representation, but why can't represents 128?

```
BitSet bset = new BitSet();
bset.set(7);
byte[] bitarray = bset.toByteArray();
for (byte b: bitarray)
 System.out.println(b);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because there are only *signed* integer types in Java. First bit of 8-bit 10000000<sub>2</sub> byte is 1 which [signifies negative number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). Thus the range of `byte` type in Java is <-128; 127>. Check this out:

```
byte b = 127;
byte b2 = (byte)(b + 1);  //-128
```

Answer (score 3):

Java supports only signed [short/byte/integer/long](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

> byte: The byte data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive). The byte data type can be useful for saving memory in large arrays, where the memory savings actually matters. They can also be used in place of int where their limits help to clarify your code; the fact that a variable's range is limited can serve as a form of documentation

Comment: As a very minor aside... `char` in Java is an *unsigned* 16-bit integer type. It kind of has one unsigned type.